# Проектирование БД MS SQL Server с возможными множеств значений

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста. Проектирую БД и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Вот примерный проект БД
[image: Проект БД]

Оказалось что у 1 Persons может быть множества Services. Например:
Person {id: 1; Name: Иван; date: 07.04.2022} будет и idService {1} это нормальное явление, но если Person будет ссылаться на множества id из таблицы Service. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему

Comment: нужна промежуточная таблица связи PersonServices (IdService, IdPerson) с составным ключом по этим двум полям. А поле idService из таблицы Person нужно убрать.

Comment: @Konst, Да наверное вы правы. Попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз у персоны может быть несколько сервисов, зачем вам в таблице персоны упоминать ID сервиса? Вам следовало бы задать идентификатор для персоны.

Набор следующих таблиц можно считать хорошей реализацией:

`Person (PersonID, Name, Date)` - здесь храним информацию о каждой персоне (для чего date, кстати?).

`Services (PersonID, ServiceID)` - здесь храним связки персона-сервис.

`ServiceNames (ServiceID, Name)` - здесь храним информацию о том, как каждый сервис называется (подразумевая, что каждому `ServiceID` соответствует определенный `Name`)

##### Извлечение информации

Для получения определенного рода информации вам понадобится JOIN.

Например, чтобы получить таблицу, в которой есть и персона, и ее имя, и сервис, и название сервиса, вам будет необходимо воспользоваться join'ом: по ключу `PersonID` между таблицами `Person` и `Services`, а затем по ключу `ServiceID` между таблицами `Services` и `ServiceNames` .

Логика запроса:

Выбрать все значения из таблицы **Person** объединить с **Services** по ключу **Person.PersonID** = **Services.PersonID** объединить с **ServiceNames** по ключу **Services.ServiceID** = **ServiceNames.ServiceID**

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку) Date? Это же предполагаемый проект, его на самом деле не будет! А как примерно будет выгладить запрос к такой структуре БД?

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)

Comment: Отлично, пожалуйста)